# How to make two independent instance of a ControlTemplate In a window?

Tags: binding, mvvm, mvvm-light, controltemplate

i have a controltemplate with a textbox and a button,the button open a sub form to select something and show selected item in the textbox,like this:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CreateParam">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Content="select" Command="{Binding ShowSpecItemViewommand}"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="2"/>
            <TextBox Margin="2" Text="{Binding Param}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="patameter" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

and i have a property in the viewmodel like this:

```
 public string param;
    public string Param
    {
        get
        {
            return param;
        }
        set
        {
            param = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Param");
        }
    }
```

and now i want to create two independent instance of that control in a window,but when i select a value for the first instance,both of them have been changed.should i define two property?and how can i bind them to the control template?
i'm not sure that every one can understand what i mean,so i hope someone edit my question:)

Answer (score 0):

How do you use the Control Template? To which Control do you attach this template? Is it a template for a custom control you have? Is it a template to a known control?

How do you instantiate the DataContext for the Control Template?

While you can implement what you want using ControlTemplate (and a custom control), and if you have many (i.e. much more than two, and all over) instances of your object a ControlTemplate may be the right paradigm, you'll be way better off using **DataTemplate**, or UserControl. There is more than one way to achieve what you want, but the code below is considered the "canonical" solution:

Say Param is a property of MyVM object. Then your XAML file should be:

```
<Window
    x:Class="SO.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:so="clr-namespace:SO"
    Height="200" Width="350"
    Title="SO Sample"
    >
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type so:MyVM}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Content="select" Command="{Binding ShowSpecItemViewommand}"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBox Margin="2" Text="{Binding Param}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="patameter" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl>
            <so:MyVM Param="1234" />
        </ContentControl>
        <ContentControl>
            <so:MyVM Param="5678" />
        </ContentControl>        
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```